# Replace special characters in SQLITE TEXT record

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I got a SQLITE database in android application. In order to increase application performance i want to do some refinement on DB before adding it to android app.

In order to do this:

I want to **remove/replace special characters** in *Name* field of *Account* table.
Unicode of those special characters are in range 8204-8207 (0x200C ~ 0x200F).
What is the correct SQL syntax to update Account Table?

Answer (score 4):

SQLite supports the REPLACE function.  See this documentation:  http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Therefore, you should be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Account
SET Name= REPLACE(Name,'char-to-replace','replacement');
```

Comment: So how can i represent unicode character 0x200C?  i don't know how to represent Unicode char in SQLite syntax.

Comment: @VSB Java supports Unicode strings. If you cannot do that, use a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) encoded in UTF-8: `CAST(x'e2808c' AS TEXT)`

Comment: I'm newbie in SQLITE. So can you please complete sample code for character 0x200C?